# dnlib after ModuleDefMD.Write(file, options) Assembly attributes are deleted

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, .net-4.0, dnlib

Module Creation process

```
var file = Console.ReadLine();
var moduleContext = ModuleDef.CreateModuleContext();
var moduleCreationOptions = new ModuleCreationOptions(moduleContext, CLRRuntimeReaderKind.Mono);
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
var moduleDefMD = ModuleDefMD.Load(buffer, moduleCreationOptions);
var moduleWriterOptions = new ModuleWriterOptions(moduleDefMD);
moduleWriterOptions.MetadataLogger = DummyLogger.NoThrowInstance;
moduleWriterOptions.MetadataOptions.Flags |=
      MetadataFlags.PreserveStringsOffsets
    | MetadataFlags.PreserveUSOffsets
    | MetadataFlags.PreserveBlobOffsets
    | MetadataFlags.PreserveExtraSignatureData;
moduleWriterOptions.Cor20HeaderOptions.Flags = ComImageFlags.ILOnly;
```

Add Static Method with single instruction ret and call it in Module cctor

```
var methodDef = new MethodDefUser(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), MethodSig.CreateStatic(moduleDefMD.CorLibTypes.Void));
methodDef.IsStatic = true;
methodDef.Body = new CilBody();
methodDef.Body.Instructions.Add(new Instruction(OpCodes.Ret));
moduleDefMD.GlobalType.Methods.Add(methodDef);
var cctorInstructions = moduleDefMD.GlobalType.FindOrCreateStaticConstructor().Body.Instructions;
cctorInstructions.Insert(0, new Instruction(OpCodes.Call, methodDef));
```

Write ModuleDefMD

```
var output = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), "output." + Path.GetExtension(file));
moduleDefMD.Write(output);
```

Result
assembly attributes are deleted, only single one is left is [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")], nothing else, no Assembly Name, no Assembly Company etc it causes problems with Assembly.GetAssembly().GetName

I tried to create another project with the same parameters and conditions i.e same .NET Framework versions, same ModuleDefMD writing process, I tried to do everything the same but nothing is help me, this is just like a curse, I'm deeply learing dnlib sources and I didn't found anything interesting that can help me to solve this problem. I open [issue](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/issues/489) on dnlib GitHub

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, when I was resolving CustomAttributes via reflection I used to be removing them